# Equivalent of !Ref in aws cdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am currently using aws-cdk to generate a cloudformation template and I would like to access a parameters defined with

```py
CfnParameter(self, id="Platform", type="String", default="My Platform")
```

with a reference (Like `!Ref Platform`  in a cloudformation template)

Any of you know what is the equivalent of a Ref in the aws cdk.

Here is the yaml equivalent of the parameter I defined above

```
Parameters:
  Platform:
    Type: String
    Default: "My Platform"
```

Answer (score 7):

It depends on which construct you are using.

For low-level constructs, so called CFN resources, you can use the `ref` property.
For high-level constructs, you should check the API for xxx_id property.
In the example below, the cfn resource uses `ref` property, whereas the high-level VPC construct uses `vpc_id` property.

```
my_vpc = _ec2.Vpc(
tgw = _ec2.CfnTransitGateway(...)
tgw_attachment = _ec2.CfnTransitGatewayAttachment(
            self,
            id="tgw-myvpc",
            transit_gateway_id=tgw.ref,
            vpc_id=my_vpc.vpc_id,
            ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for someone still looking for an answer you can do:

```
const plataform = new CfnParameter(this, "Platform", {
   type: "String",
   default: "MyPlataform"
});

const deploymentRole = new Role(this, 'DeploymentRole', {
    assumedBy: new ArnPrincipal("Some ARN"),
    roleName: Fn.join("-",[plataform.valueAsString,"role"])
});
```